# Diagnosing Perl handling UTF8

Tags: perl, utf-8

I have a script which reads xlsx files using a Spreadsheet::XLSX module, prepares a message using a string interpolation:

```
$message = "this is my message in my language $xlscontents";
```

and then sends it by email using Email::Sender::Simple. Pragma 'use utf8' is set.

The issue is, while the string literal (where national characters are used) is displayed correctly, the variable $xlscontents is not: although the string held in the variable already is encoded in UTF-8, each UTF character is treated as if it was a series of separate 8-bit characters which are re-encoded separately. The end result is, of course, garbage. At least this is how I see it, because only the fragment which had been read into $xlscontents variable is spoiled; the literal in my language is displayed correctly. I also looked into the email message with a hex viewer and it looks this way.

My theory is that although Perl knows that the string literal is UTF-encoded, it seems to believe that the variable is 8-bit ASCII (or another 8-bit code) and attemptes to encode it during the interpolation. My questions:
* How could I verify this theory? Is there a way to screen the Perl variable contents byte by byte?
* How could I inform Perl that the variable is already UTF-encoded and does not need re-encoding?

The script had been working well using on-screen messaging only, but when I started playing with emails, I found out that all the texts were spoiled. So I turned utf support on, and since then literals are displayed properly, but the variable contents are not, si apparently I'm still missing something.

Comment: I am not sure, but seems like you should try to decode the `$xlscontents` after reading from spreadsheet.. Please show some of your code

Comment: Two quick notes before I leave: 1) The name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL". 2) The `use utf8;` pragma tells Perl that the source code is encoded using UTF-8. It's unlikely to have any relevance at all here.

Comment: man Encode and/or man utf8 should be your starting points.

Comment: If you want to see what Perl thinks is in your string, `printf "%vd\n", $str` will show you the codepoints in dotted decimal format.

Comment: Could you provide the code you use to send the email?

Comment: Re "*My theory is that although Perl knows that the string literal is UTF-encoded*",  No, Perl doesn't know the encoding of strings, or if they are text at all.

Comment: @Jasio, Could you at least confirm that you use  Email::Sender::Simple's `sendmail` and that you compose the email using `Email::Simple->create`? I don't want to spend time writing an answer around these if that's not what you are using!

Comment: @ikegami, yes, I create the message using Email::Simple->create and send it using the sendmail function.

Comment: But as @Håkon Hægland suggested, the root of the problem was not decoding $xlscontents after reading,

Answer (score 0):

In case someone googles this question: 
since Perl has its own internal string representation, to make sure that the strings are properly handled you need to decode them after they're read from the sheet or command line:

```
$value = Encode::decode( "UTF8", ($sheet -> {Cells} [0] [0]) -> {Val} ); 
$value = ($sheet -> {Cells} [0] [0]) -> {Val} ); utf8::decode($value);
```

If the file is read directly, the conversion may also be specified at the opening. There are more caveats related to Unicode, so it would be best to read https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html first.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Devel::Peek to see how the string is "encoded".

```
 use Devel::Peek;
 Dump( $xlscontents );
```

will print the content and the internal representation of the String to STDERR. If it contains correct encoded ut8, but does not have the UTF8-flag set, you can use

```
 Encode::_utf8_on($xlscontents)
```

to fix this. Please read http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html#Messing-with-Perl%27s-Internals first.

Comment: Never ever use `_utf8_on`!!! Doing so is inherently buggy. If you want to decode, use `Encode::decode_utf8` or the builtin `utf8::decode`.

Comment: I know this is your opinion, but i disagree. . Especially in a legacy environment which was in part written for perl prior than 5.8 you have software requiring the strings to be encoded in utf8, but the utf-8 flag to be turned off. So its quite normal to ensure that the urf-8 flag is turned off, by calling Encode::_utf8_off (and __utf8_on in the other case). When you are lucky to only work with newer software, you certainly would not use this.

Comment: That's what utf8::upgrade and utf8::downgrade are for. Use those instead

Comment: I pasted a small perl test-script to http://pastebin.com/4eNBpKaa Only the Encode::_utf8_off works as expected in my eyes.

Comment: In your pastebin, you used `_utf8_off` to encode. Doing so is buggy. (e.g. `_utf8_off` will fail to encode `my $string = "\xE9"`;) If you want to encode, use `Encode::encode_utf8`, `utf8::encode`, etc. You can see this has the same desired affect as `_utf8_off` [here](http://pastebin.com/wENGcuGS).

Comment: I am using "_utf8_off" to provide perl-legacy software with my data. Neither utf8::upgrade or utf8::downgrade or Encode::encode_utf8 or Encode::decode_utf8 works for that. utf8::encode works - but is in no means clearer to me than just telling perl IGNORE THE UTF-8 flag. Btw:  `perl -Mutf8 -MEncode -MDevel::Peek -e 'my $string = "\xE9"; Dump($string); Encode::_utf8_off($string);Dump($string) '` will leave the string as is.

Comment: Re "*Neither utf8::upgrade or utf8::downgrade or Encode::encode_utf8 or Encode::decode_utf8 works for that*", You are mistaken. You are simply not aware of how to fix your bugs. I've already shown you how to fix one of your misuses of `_utf8_on`/`_utf8_off`/`is_utf8`, and I'll help you with other should you ask. /// Telling Perl to ignore to turn off the `UTF8` flag is not a clear way of encoding (unlike using `utf8::encode`, which is just as efficient), especially since it doesn't always work. /// Re "*will leave the string as is*", Exactly as I said. it completely failed to encode it.

Comment: _utf8_off  does not encode a string, it removes a flag. So if you have perl software that requires you to have unicode encoded content without a utf-8 flag (every unicode-aware perl package written prior 2002/2003) you have to do this.

Comment: Re "*_utf8_off does not encode a string*", That's why I've been telling you, but you insist it's a clear way of doing that! /// Re "*So if you have perl software that requires you to have unicode encoded content without a utf-8 flag*", That's the very definition of encoding+downgrading (except encoding already downgrades, so you can skip that step). You've already shown that `_utf8_off` doesn't produce unicode encoded content without a utf-8 flag for `"\xE9"` (It does for `"\x{100}"`, so it *sometimes* works, unlike `utf8::encode` which always works.)

Comment: Furthermore, 5.8, only came out in 2002, and it has a different Unicode model than 5.6. `upgrade` and `downgrade` didn't even exist before 5.8, so code written before 2002 is irrelevant here.

Comment: @ikegami Ok, because you asked for it i created a small pastebin with an example. the sub nice_quote just REPRESENTS old legacy code. BTW - Debian started shipping with perl 5.8 in 2005 - and lots of people where using 5.6 in these days. As some are still using 5.10 nowadays. http://pastebin.com/VEBVRSW4

Comment: `nice_quote` expects text encoded using UTF-8, so we need to encode its inputs and decode its outputs. Replace `Encode::_utf8_off($string2);` with `utf8::encode($string2);`. `nice_quote` returns text encoded using UTF-8. Replace `Encode::_utf8_on($str);` with `utf8::decode($str);`. Your method fails for `my $string2 = "\xE9l\xE8ve";`.

Comment: Of course it fails for "\xE9l\xE8ve" - this is not an utf8-encoded string. And i know that whenever Encode::_utf8_off( ... ) works, utf8::encode( ... ) would work too. I do not agree with your opinion that using  Encode::_utf8_off is the beginning of all evil, sorry :(

Comment: Re "*Of course it fails for "\xE9l\xE8ve" - this is not an utf8-encoded string.*", true, but neither is `"élève"` when `use utf8;` is in effect. Do `"élève" eq "\xE9l\xE8ve"` and you'll find they're the same string, but you code turns it in into garbage because your code is buggy.

Comment: **I've demonstrated that every one of your uses `_utf8_on` is buggy.** That makes it fact, not opinon. **Even the documentation of `_utf8_on` and `_utf8_off` tells you not to use it!** Keep using if you want, but please stop spreading misinformation.

Comment: This does get way to personal - I think its time to stop :)